# Odoo 15 inherit js function

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I try to inherit onClickSendMessage() of mail chatter js in odoo 15 https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/models/chatter/chatter.js#L140

here is my js code

```
/** @odoo-module **/

import { patch } from 'web.utils';
import { Chatter } from '@mail/components/chatter/chatter';

patch(Chatter.prototype, 'my_custom_module/static/src/js/chatter.js', {
    onClickSendMessage(ev) {
        if (this.composerView && !this.composerView.composer.isLog) {
            this.update({ composerView: clear() });
        } else {
            this.showSendMessage();
        }
    }
});
```

But when i click on this, my custom module function not call.
Anyone can help ? how to can i do this.

Comment: could you add a console.log('inside my onClickSendMessage'); inside your function onClickSendMessage ? so that you can check if it s called in your browser's console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch `mail.chatter` model using [registerInstancePatchModel](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/mail/static/src/model/model_core.js#L98) which is used to register a patch for instance methods in model

***Example:***

```js
/** @odoo-module **/

import { registerInstancePatchModel } from "@mail/model/model_core";

registerInstancePatchModel("mail.chatter", "custom_send_message", {
    onClickSendMessage() {
      
    },

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it working now.